# what exactly does CompositionContainer.ComposeExportedValue method do?

Tags: .net, mef

Does the CompositionContainer.ComposeExportedValue method take an object and make the object's export method available? I am kind of confused what this method does. All I know is that this method regsiters object with the container. How does it register objects with the container?  Does this method majically somehow make an object's export methods, or an object that has the export attribute available for other classess?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK the [`AttributedModelServices.ComposeExportedValue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd986608.aspx) extension method for [`CompositionContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.aspx) registers the given object as a part satisfying contract `T`. This means that the object will indeed be used to compose other objects which import `T`.

Perhaps more important is what it *doesn't do*:

- It doesn't try to set any properties with Import attributes. You can do that with [`AttributedModelServices.ComposeParts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.attributedmodelservices.composeparts.aspx).
- It doesn't transfer ownership of the object to the container. If the object is `IDisposable`, it will **not** be disposed when the container is disposed.

In general you should avoid these methods. Typically you would just add the necessary attributes to your class and add it to the container via a `AssemblyCatalog`.

Comment: hmm I was using servicelocator and I switched it to ComposeExportedValue and it no longer returns two results... I wonder if this is a bug